# Перекрытие прерываний dos

Tags: ассемблер, dos, tasm, прерывания

Перекрываю прерывание клавиатуры.
Полно примеров как получить введенный символ. Однако адекватных примеров с вводом символов в буфер клавиатуры - нет.
Задача:
Заменить первые пять символов латинского алфавита, цифрами. 
Мои попытки так и не увенчались успехом. Проблема в записи символов в буфер.

```
chain db 12,20h,2Eh,30h,1Eh  ; e,d,c,b,a
chain_ascii db '5','4','3','2','1'
in al,60h ; берем символ из порта 
push ax ; символ в стек
jmp old_handler ; вызов старого обработчика
pop ax 
lea di, chain 
mov cx,5
repne scasb ; по цепочке, пока не найдем соответствие
test cx,cx ; не нашли - выход, символ не заменяем.
jz exitH
inc cx ; после repne счетчик находится на след символе
mov bx,cx 
mov ch,chain_ascii[bx]
inc cl ; т.к scan-code символа на единицу больше.  
push    40h             
pop     es
mov   word ptr ES:[1Ch-2],cx ; es:[1ch] - указатель на хвост(на свободное  
; место) сдвигаем его чтобы вернутся к пред. символу
```

exitH:

Comment: А зачем работать с портами? перехватить BIOS, подставлять свое...

Comment: Ну, тут особой работы с портом нету. Просто берется значение. 
Меня больше интересует работа с буфером, что я делаю не так.
Вариант с BIOS я тоже рассматривал. С помощью пятой функции 16-го прерывания симулировать нажатие, но остановился на варианте с буфером.

Comment: Возьмите 16h прерывание, перехватите, в перехваченном выполняйте старое прерывание, а потом просто поменяйте регистр `AX` - это будет куда проще. Поверьте на слово - не стоит лезть во внутренности BIOS и железа - пусть они сами работают. Ваше дело - просто подменить выход и не более того.

Comment: Мне по заданию необходимо перекрыть девятое прерывание.
Или мне делать так:
дать отработать исходному обработчику клавиатуры.
с помощью нулевой функции 16-го прерывания глянуть символ
если подходит - извлекаю его с помощью первой функции
запихиваю свой с помощью пятой
Просто тогда будут вызовы 16-й функции, и как мне кажется вызывать внутри одного прерывания другое наверное не очень правильно

Comment: А, если так ставят задачу - тогда дело другое. Понятно, что из 9 вызывать 16 нехорошо. Тогда могу только посоветовать Фроловых - типа, http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v02/ch2_3.htm

Comment: Да я много чего уже перечитал. И это тоже видел. Всё еще осложняется тем, что не получается в дебагере с данным куском кода работать